# FFmpeg with Automator & ask Start and Stop parameters

Tags: applescript, command-line, bash, automator, automation

I use Automator together with ffmpeg which works great. A shell script command is run with two parameters:

- -ss 00:00:00 (starting)
- -t 00:00:00 (time length)

**Q: Is it possible to set the two parameters using a popup window?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked "*Is it possible to set the two parameters using a popup window?*" and the answer to that is **yes**.

**Here is one example of how it could be done:**

In between the **Ask for Finder Items** *action* and the **Run Shell Script** *action* add a **Run AppleScript** *action* with the following **AppleScript** *code*:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    display dialog "Enter the start time and length:" default answer "-ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:00" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} ¬
        with title "Set FFMPEG Start Time and Length: -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:00"
    set beginning of input to text returned of result
    return input
end run
```

Then in the **Run Shell Script** *action*, change the *script* to the following *code*:

```
start_time_and_length="$1"
shift

for f in "$@"
do
    /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2.4/bin/ffmpeg -i "$f" $start_time_and_length -c:v copy -c:a copy -f mp4 "${f%.*}.mp4"
done
```

[image: Automator Workflow]

---

**How this works:**

- The **Ask for Finder Items** *action* passes a `list` of *filesystem objects* to the next *action*.
- The **Run AppleScript** *action* uses a `display dialog` to add the *start time* and *length* to the *beginning* of the `list` passed to it from the **Ask of Finder Items** *action*.
- The **Run Shell Script** *action* receives what was returned from the **Run AppleScript** *action*, in this case the *value* of `return input` as a `list` in which its first `item` is the `text returned` from the `result` of the `display dialog`, being the start time and length. This gets set to the `start_time_and_length` *variable* and then `shift` is used to remove it from the `list` that gets passed to `for f in "$@"` to process the remaining `items` in the `list`.

---

Note: If you have a issue using the **AppleScript** *code*, shown above, then you could use the following as a workaround:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set tempList to {}
    display dialog "Enter the start time and length:" default answer "-ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:00" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} ¬
        with title "Set FFMPEG Start Time and Length: -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:00"
    set end of tempList to text returned of result
    repeat with i from 1 to (count of input)
        set end of tempList to item i of input
    end repeat
    copy tempList to input
    return input
end run
```

Comment: Both AppleScript works perfectly. I try to solve the two values with two separate input window, but it is still perfect. Thank you for your time!